# php query array in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phalcon

I am using php phalcon5 framework. I have 2 columns on a product table. Product title and keyword. The product title contains 1 complete sentence and the keyword contains multiple comma separated words. I have done different queries but am getting unexpected results. How do I get the right results?

[Table]

```
table -> products
column -> product_title, keywords

-----------------------------------------------
product_title       | keywords
-----------------------------------------------
three piece         | women,cloth,three,piece
shari               | women,cloth
Kurti               | cloth,women
-----------------------------------------------
```

[Query Results]

```
Query1: women cloth
Result: three piece, shari
Expected Result: three piece, shari, Kurti 

Query2: cloth women
Result: Kurti
Expected Result: three piece, shari, Kurti

Query3: women/cloth
Result: Three piece, shari, Kurti
Expected Result: three piece, shari, Kurti

Query4: cloths
Result: No Data Found
Expected Result: three piece, shari, Kurti
```

[Controller]

```
$data = trim($this->request->getPost('q'));

$query = Products::find(["keywords LIKE :key: OR product_title LIKE :data:",
 "bind" => ["data" => '%'. $data .'%',"key" => '%'.$data.'%'],
]);

if($query->count() > 0)
{
   $this->view->setVar('pro',$query);
   $this->view->pick('index/query');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to take in account is that you can use only one bind param, ex. data, and reemploy it in either keywords and product_title comparison:

```
$query = Products::find(["keywords LIKE :data: OR product_title LIKE :data:",
 "bind" => ["data" => '%'. $data .'%'],
]);
```

In the other hand, you should to explode your query string to prevent it from affecting the words order, and repeat your keywords/product_title comparison with each of them:

```
$words = array_map('trim', preg_split('|\s+|', $this->request->getPost('q')));

$params = [];
foreach ($words as $key => $word) {
    $params['conditions'] .= isset($params['conditions']) ? ' AND ' : '';
    $params['conditions'] .= "(keywords LIKE :word".$key.": OR product_title LIKE :word".$key.":)";
    $params['bind']['word'.$key] = '%'. $word .'%';
}

$query = Products::find($params);
```

Comment: After applying your 2nd rules Getting error like : " Warning: Undefined array key "conditions" in /var/www/html/f/apps/front/controllers/IndexController.php on line 126
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number "

Comment: In my case both keywords and product_title not allowing same $key. [tested your 1st rule]

Comment: To solve your warning you can initializate `$params = ['conditions' => '', 'bind' => []];`

Comment: If your query string are "WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4" you should to see something like 

`Array
(
    [conditions] => (product_title LIKE :word0: OR keywords LIKE :word0:) AND (product_title LIKE :word1: OR keywords LIKE :word1:) AND (product_title LIKE :word2: OR keywords LIKE :word2:) AND (product_title LIKE :word3: OR keywords LIKE :word3:)
    [bind] => Array
        (
            [word0] => %WORD1%
            [word1] => %WORD2%
            [word2] => %WORD3%
            [word3] => %WORD4%
        )

)
`

Comment: Sorry about format, but I don't know how to well format in comments :( But this params should be correct as find function param. I test it in one own model and returns valid data from database.

Comment: Chess! I enabled fulltext in my data table. am i doing wrong? or it's good practice for this type of query?

Comment: The best thing you can do is benchmarking your query. Fill your table with one millon of sample rows and get execution time of your query with and without fulltext index, so you can compare if you get a considerable better time or not.